# ReWrite Rules htaccess confusion

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

So I am new to the ReWrite Rules in htaccess and could use some help

I currently have a php page poll.php base template for the information it gets from PHPMyAdmin gets the information for the poll through the pollcode for this example it will be vmxez so poll.php?code=vmxez displays correctly how I want it to but I am trying to rewrite it so domain.com/vmxez shows what is on domain.com/poll.php?code=vmxez any help would be great been fighting this one for 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rewrite module is installed and enabled,

```
# Turn on the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
# Set the base path
RewriteBase /
# Rewrite an exact match of /vmxez
RewriteRule ^/vmxez$ /poll.php?code=vmxez
```

If your goal is actually send all non-PHP script requests to poll.php:

```
# Skip rewrites for direct file requests (e.g. PHP scripts)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Capture the path requested and pass it as a parameter
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /poll.php?code=$1
```

Comment: Thank you the second is working for what I wanted however if i just go to the domain name it doesn't bring me to index.php its bringing me to the poll.php page. You have a workaround for this?

Comment: Sure, see my edit. I changed `*` to `+` so only non-empty path requests go to poll.php.  An empty path request will fall through to index.php.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I knew the 50 rep would get this solved.

Comment: I'll award in 23 hours.

Comment: Just getting back on here, I awarded it. Thanks again.